# kNN-DTW time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, data-science, knn, dtw

I found from various online sources that the time complexity for DTW is quadratic. On the other hand, I also found that standard kNN has linear time complexity. However, when pairing them together, does kNN-DTW have quadratic or cubic time?

In essence, does the time complexity of kNN solely depend on the metric used? I have not found any clear answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful here. Let's say you have `n` time series in your 'training' set (let's call it this, even though you are not really training with kNN) of length `l`. Computing the DTW between a pair of time series has a asymptotic complexity of O(`l` * `m`) where `m` is your maximum warping window. As `m` <= `l` also O(`l`^2) holds. (although there might be more efficient implementations, i don't think they are actually faster in practice in most cases, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping#Complexity)). Classifying a time series using kNN requires you to compute the distance between that time series and all time series in the training set which would mean `n` comparisons, linear with respect to `n`.

So your final complexity would be in O(`l` * `m` * `n`) or O(`l`^2 * `n`). In words: the complexity is quadratic with respect to time series length and linear with respect to the number of training examples.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "standalone DTW"? DTW just computes a distance between two time series. kNN using DTW requires a set of labelled training/reference data and provides a classification. In my view, it does not make sense to compare the complexity of these two tasks as if they are interchangeable.

Comment: Also, if my answer was useful to you, please give it an upvote and consider marking it as accepted.